# Access fields of main class

Tags: javascript, oop

I have classes named Car and Engine.

```
class Car {
     constructor() {
        this.engine = new Engine();
        this.start = false;
     }

    startCar() {
         // some code
     } 
}

class Engine {
     startEngine() {
          if(start == false) { // Car.start
               startCar() // Car.startCar
          }
     }
}
```

I want to call startCar method and access start field from *startEngine* method. Is there any other way to access these fields & methods without giving these to *Engine* class as parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the startEngine() method in the Car's constructor:

```
 constructor() {
    this.engine = new Engine();
    this.start = false;

    this.engine.startEngine = this.engine.startEngine.bind(this);
 }
```

Then you can use 'this' in the startEngine method:

```
class Engine {
     startEngine() {
          if(this.start == false) { // Car.start
               this.start = true;
          }
     }
}
```

and access the engine's startEngine() method from the car's startCar() method:

```
startCar() {
     this.engine.startEngine();
 }
```

You could also access the startCar() method from inside the startEngine() method:

```
class Engine {
     startEngine() {
          if(this.start == false) { // Car.start
               this.startCar();
          }
     }
}
```